# Applying xpath to result of xpath operation

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Can I apply Xpath in a "nested" way?
I tried below solution, I was expecting first line to return a single `<li>` element, from which I could then extract its link by applying 2nd xpath expression. However I seem to do something wrong, the 2nd line still returns first a found globally, not in my `<li>`.

```
aaa = response.xpath('//ul/li[@class="navitem")]')
bbb = aaa.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
```

Comment: Have you peeked at _aaa_? It should be a list.

Comment: In this case, I think that a single xpath `'//ul/li[@class="navitem")][1]//a'` would also work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
aaa = response.xpath('//ul/li[@class="navitem")]')
bbb = aaa[0].xpath('.//a/@href').extract()
```

Note the period `.` in the 2nd XPath. This will select the `@href` attribute of all anchor elements that are descendants of the `li` elements with `class="navitem"`. Without the period `.`, the expression `aaa[0].xpath('//a/@href').extract()` will return the `@href` attribute from all anchor tags in the entire document.

Comment: I think it should be _aaa[0]..._. It might be worth emphasizing that without the leading dot, OP's xpath will search the entire document.

Comment: Thanks, I stupidly answered without testing my solution because I knew that the period was missing!